# Regular Expression - Negating strings

Tags: regex-negation

I have a file in the following format

AAA
BBB
League="NFL"
League="CFB"
League="NBA"
League="CBK"
CCC
DDD

I would like to list only the lines containing League but not NFL or NBA.  So from the above, I only want:

League="CFB"
League="CBK"

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
/League="[^(NFL)|(NBA)]"/
```

Comment: it should be global, enables iterative matching `/g` and match more time `.*`

Comment: Thank you for the example but I think this solution works only because it eliminates the sports starting with N because when I replace NBA with CBK, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use a regular expression? (Is it for homework?)

If not you could read the file in and filter it like so:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("filePath"));

String line = in.readLine();
List<String> myList = newArrayList<String>();

while(line != null){
    if ((line.startsWith("League")) && 
        (!line.contains("NFL")) && 
        (!line.contains("NBA"))){

           myList.add(line)

        }
 }
```

To populate a list of Strings containing all of the strings from the file that started with League, but that did not contain NFL or NBA.

Doing this with a regex match on a line would be ugly.

Comment: Thank you for the example.  However, no it is not for homework and I need a regex.

Answer (score 0):

the last two will be interpreted as
/League="[^NFLBA]"/